# Binding Two Database Tables to the Same Datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, datagrid

I would like to know how I would be able to use two different tables from more Sql Compact database in the same wpf datagrid.  I have two tables currently, Accounts and AccountType.  There is a foreign key in Accounts to link it to the AccountType in which it is the ID number of the type.  I also have a field in Accounts to link it to a parent account (essentially a foreign key to another account's id).  Below is the wpf I have to bind the datagrid to the Accounts table.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <my:MyAccountantDBDataSet x:Key="myAccountantDBDataSet" />
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="accountsViewSource" Source="{Binding Path=Accounts, Source={StaticResource myAccountantDBDataSet}}" />
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="accountTypeViewSource" Source="{Binding Path=AccountType, Source={StaticResource myAccountantDBDataSet}}" />
</Window.Resources>

            <DataGrid Background="DimGray" Name="GridAccounts" CanUserAddRows="True" CanUserDeleteRows="True" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource accountsViewSource}}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Path=AccountName}"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Description" Binding="{Binding Path=AccountDesc}" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Number" Binding="{Binding Path=AccountNumber}"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Type" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Parent Account" />
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
```

What I would like to do, is bind the Type column to the AccountType table and show the Type Name, not the Type id.  Also, same idea for the Parent Account, I don't want to show the id number, but rather the Account Name if it has a parent account. How can I do this to these two columns?

Comment: Wait, this can easily be achieved by `JOIN`ING the tables. You can read about [JOIN](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you create a view joining the two tables in the database and then query the view from C#?
This way all the processing is done on the database and could be more efficient than from your application.

Comment: Thanks Kevin.  I know all about joining, I just was wondering if there was a different way with binding or not.